# WPF, UserControl, Building dynamic attribute based data, VB, .NET, WPF Controls

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I'm WPF newbe, with a UserControl, inside the user control, I want to bind to an item type Property stored in my dataContext (Called "AssignType")... "AssignType" determines a control to hold a "value" property.

AssignType could be a Textbox, Richtextbox, ComboBox, DatePicker, RadioButton...etc

the Value field needs to bind to the "AssignType" control using 2 way binding - further more, the items data (eg. combo source) also needs to be bound

the only way I have managed to achieve this is to create a custom control, examine the DataContext and building up 'Assigned Controls' manually,  I then apply any changes on the Controls Changed Event,

my problem is, this just doesnt seem 'very WPF'... 
what is the correct way to do such a task?

(sample load current method)

```
Select Case AssignedType
    Case Items.FieldTypes.IsText, 
        Tb = New TextBox
        Try
            If Not IsNothing(Source.ValueItem) Then _
                Tb.Text = Source.ValueItem
        Catch
        End Try
        Tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, BindingSource)
        AddChild(Tb)

    Case Items.FieldTypes.IsDropDownValue
        cbo = New ComboBox
        cbo.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
        PopulateComboValues(cbo, Source)
        AddChild(cbo)

    Case Items.FieldTypes.IsDateValue
        Dt = New DatePicker
        Dt.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
        Try
            If IsDate(Source.ValueItem) Then Dt.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Source.ValueItem)
        Catch
        End Try
        Dt.Margin = New Thickness(5, 0, 5, 0)
        AddChild(Dt)

    Case Items.FieldTypes.IsLargeText
        Rtf = New RichTextBox
        Rtf.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch
        Try
            If Not IsNothing(Source.ValueItem) AndAlso Source.ValueItem.Trim <> "" Then
                Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(Source.ValueItem))
                Rtf.Selection.Load(ms, DataFormats.Xaml)
            End If
            Rtf.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = True
        Catch
        End Try
        Rtf.Height = 100
        AddChild(Rtf)

    Case Items.FieldTypes.IsImageList
```

Comment: What is the use of caps-lock on the title? Down vote from me until the title is written normally. This doesn't really attract people to answer your question.

Comment: @Dykam: I never did figure that out either...

Comment: I was going to clean up the title, but cannot make any sense of the question. The sample code doesn't compile, either.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it isn't very WPF-ish. this is what we use [DataTemplates](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) for.